Aluminum quality by ASTM B209 cross refers to 4015,4016,4017 AMS-QQ-A-250/8?
Client is asking if we can issue quality certificate by 4015,4016,4017 AMS-QQ-A-250/8 instead of
ASTM B 209 for aluminum coils AA5052 H32

FIX YOUR CAPS KEY - YOU ARE SHOUTING AT US.

And can you? Find the specs they want, see if your product meets them.
